# What is the best way to get initial JSON in Rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Tell me please what is the best way to get initial JSON in Rails.

Now I get it on $(document).ready() event. But users will wait approximately 2 or 3 seconds. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

If your just want to send some JSON to client-side (assuming its available at request) you can send it to your view:

```
@some_json = {:foo => bar}.to_json
```

Then again you are only required to use `$(document).ready()` if your JSON depends on the DOM.

Comment: The question was how to send JSON :) I meant - creating <script> tags directly in html and creating global json, which will be attached to the window object? Is it normally?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I ran into the same issue.  This is how I am approaching the problem to get a view model bound to Knockout.  Hopefully it is of some value to a future traveller/OP.

```
<div id="initial-content" data="<%= @initial_content%>" /> #JSON string created in controller method

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var initialContent = $.parseJSON($('#initial-content').attr('data'));
        ko.applyBindings(app.product.model(initialContent), $('#content_div')[0]);
    });
</script>
```

app.product.model() above is just a function that takes a JS object and returns my fully baked Knockout view model.

You're still loading the model during document ready, but you're not waiting for document ready to request the JSON from the server.  I think that's the problem you're trying to solve.  If not, my apologies.